# %100 space on ubuntu/media

Tags: disk-usage

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1969072       4   1969068   1% /dev
tmpfs             396184    1408    394776   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        3928032 1629288   2298744  42% /cdrom
/dev/loop0        999296  999296         0 100% /rofs
/cow             1980912 1980912         0 100% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1980912    1192   1979720   1% /tmp
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1980912      80   1980832   1% /run/shm
none              102400      84    102316   1% /run/user
/dev/sr0          384018  384018         0 100% /media/ubuntu/HP DJ1510
/dev/sda2       19091584   45088  18053628   1% /media/ubuntu/139df09d-a0b5-4567-86c8-ebb26dd88d87
/dev/sda1       19091584 3842632  14256084  22% /media/ubuntu/2cd26b6a-032b-40d9-95ef-1804ffc01065
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I just installed and it gives this error. I also formatted 10 minutes ago because I had this error and made

```
20 gb to /
20 gb to /home
4 gb to /swap but I cant solve this problem. Why do I have this error?
```

I am a programmer and i install programs like inteljidea, jdk,jre.So, should I change size of things? I have 500 GB HDD so i can give more space.

Comment: Looks like you are still running the installer system (with a copy-on-write root file system, as it seems), not your installed system. Maybe time to reboot, without the installation media?

Comment: Ah, and `/dev/sr0` is a DVD-/CD-ROM drive or similar. The media in there always has 100% used, as it is read-only, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was the one asking the question. I restarted and now i am on my ubuntu that was i prepared while installing. As Dubu said , i did not realize but i was on dvd ubuntu so my user name was ubuntu. I should have understood from that username because mine was not that. As i forgot my password and i thought , after restart i could see this page with my user logged, i now registred new account to answer. Thank you Dubu.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. I will close this question since because it was based on a misunderstanding it is unlikely to help anyone else. Also, please see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge your accounts.